# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join' caused by *.pyc

Tags: python, pyc

I have created on mac 1 line file:
 myfile.py

```
import networkx
```

I get:

```
    ['Apricot', 'Aquamarine', 'Bittersweet', 'Black', 'Blue', 'BlueGreen', 'BlueViolet', 'BrickRed', 'Brown', 'BurntOrange', 'CadetBlue', 'CarnationPink', 'Cerulean', 'CornflowerBlue', 'Cyan', 'Dandelion', 'DarkOrchid', 'Emerald', 'ForestGreen', 'Fuchsia', 'Goldenrod', 'Gray', 'Green', 'GreenYellow', 'JungleGreen', 'Lavender', 'LimeGreen', 'Magenta', 'Mahogany', 'Maroon', 'Melon', 'MidnightBlue', 'Mulberry', 'NavyBlue', 'OliveGreen', 'Orange', 'OrangeRed', 'OrchidPeach', 'Periwinkle', 'PineGreen', 'Plum', 'ProcessBlue', 'Purple', 'RawSienna', 'Red', 'RedOrange', 'RedViolet', 'Rhodamine', 'RoyalBlue', 'RoyalPurple', 'RubineRed', 'Salmon', 'SeaGreen', 'Sepia', 'SkyBlue', 'SpringGreen', 'Tan', 'TealBlue', 'Thistle', 'Turquoise', 'Violet', 'VioletRed', 'WhiteWild', 'Strawberry', 'Yellow', 'YellowGreen', 'YellowOrange']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import networkx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import networkx.classes
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/classes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .function import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/networkx/classes/function.py", line 509, in <module>
    @not_implemented_for('directed')
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in _not_implemented_for
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 232, in decorate
    evaldict, __wrapped__=func)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 219, in create
    self = cls(func, name, signature, defaults, doc, module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 115, in __init__
    formatvalue=lambda val: "", *argspec)[1:-1])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 869, in formatargspec
    return '(' + string.join(specs, ', ') + ')'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'
```

I did through terminal, it worked:

```
    :~ yev$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkx
>>> print 'test'
test
>>> G = networkx.barabasi_albert_graph(2,1,1)
>>> print G.degree().values()
[1, 1]
>>>
```

After I did it again, it did not work.
Finally, I realised that the problem was in the following: I was executing import networkx from different directories ( typically I work from Desktop), and it did not work until I deleted the test file I had in Desktop which was created previously( by me). That file was of the name:

> string.pyc

Hence question is: What did happen. Why this *.pyc file was causing problem. Do all *.pyc files create this type of issues?

Answer (score 2):

`*.pyc` file is compiled version of your code. This is the bytecode executed by python vm. If your `*.py` file changes, python replaces the `*.pyc` file with updated one.

In your case it looks like you had `string.py` file that was compiled to `string.pyc` in one of folders you were working from. This file shadowed the standard string module (home dir of your project is always looked up first).
This made inspect.py module import your `string.py` instead of standard lib one. And there is the error from.